# Unit Test Configurations Files with Environment Properties

Tags: spring, junit, java-8, spring-test

Is there a way to unit test if environment properties get set inside a configuration file? I am using spring without spring boot and have my test set up with the following

Test

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { carConfig.class, AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class })
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class CarConfigTest {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Test
    public void propertiesConfigTest() {

    }
}
```

Class/function being tested

```
public Properties propertiesConfig(){
    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.put(endpoints, env.getProperty(car.endpoints));
    ...
    return props;
}
```

Comment: When you say "environment properties" you mean your `env` bean on @Autowired? Is it throwing NPE on the `env.getProperty` call?

Comment: Correct, I see an NPE error

Comment: Ok, I will try to replicate your code when I get home.